# Array in object from data model comes nil

Tags: ios, swift, object, datamodel

I have a model class called Coupon and it has an array of objects called Array! 
When I create an object from from Coupon class the array inside of this object comes nil and it gets an error. What am I doing wrong?

```
class Coupon {
    private var _date: String!
    private var _editor: String!
    private var _predictions: Array<Prediction>?

var date: String {
    get {
        return _date
    }
}

var editor: String {
    get {
        return _editor
    }
}

var predictions: Array<Prediction>? {
    get {
        return _predictions
    }
    set {
        self._predictions = predictions
    }
}
}
```

And the controller is as follows: c.predictions![0] gives nil error

```
let ref = DataService.ds.REF_COUPONS.queryOrdered(byChild: "date")
    ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let couponDict = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
            let c_key = snapshot.key
            let c = Coupon(couponKey: c_key, couponData: couponDict)
            let childSnapShot = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "predictions")
            if let snapshots = childSnapShot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {

                for snap in snapshots{

                    let p_key = snap.key
                    let p = Prediction(predictionKey: p_key, predictionData: snap.value as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)
                    self.predictions.append(p) 
                    c.predictions![0] = self.predictions[0] <--- ERROR LINE
                }
            }
            self.coupons.append(c)
        }
        self.couponsTableView.reloadData()
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Because it's value is `nil` by default. So `predictions!` will result in `trying to unwrap an optional whose value is nil` kind of error.

You should create new array there:

```
c.predictions = [self.predictions[0]]
```

Also there is no need for backing fields in swift. Your `Coupon` class can be reduced to:

```
class Coupon {
    private(set) var date: String!
    private(set) var editor: String!
    var predictions: Array<Prediction>?
}
```

<sup>**`private(set)` means that the value can only be set within this class.**</sup>

The definition line of predictions `var predictions: Array<Prediction>?` can be replaced to have default value of empty array:

```
class Coupon {
    private(set) var date: String!
    private(set) var editor: String!
    var predictions: [Prediction] = []
}
```

<sup>**`[Prediction]` is same as `Array<Prediction>`**</sup>

Once it has default value of empty array instead of creating new array you can safely append to it:

`c.predictions.append(self.predictions[0])`

Also note that your code `c.predictions[0] = self.predictions[0]` would work never even in this case because the array is defaulted to empty has not `0`th element.

Comment: Thank you that was a great explanation ))

Answer (score 0):

Element in `predictions` array at index `0` doesn't exist, so you can't replace it with new element. I suggest you to replace `_predictions` array with empty `predictions` array

```
var predictions = [Prediction]()
```

then you can append new element to this array like this:

```
c.predictions.append(self.predictions[0])
```

Also in your case there is no need to use property with getter and setter and you can also use `struct` instead of `class`

```
struct Coupon {
    var date: String
    var editor: String
    var predictions = [Prediction]()

    // your convenience init
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create the class Coupon with `let c = Coupon(couponKey: c_key, couponData: couponDict)` your array is not initialize, so that's normal to have an error when you are trying to use it in the line `c.predictions![0] = self.predictions[0] <--- ERROR LINE`, your object Coupon you could initialize the array predictions as an empty array like this

```
class Coupon {
private var _date: String!
private var _editor: String!
private var _predictions = [Prediction]()
```